# ASP.net MVC @html.dropdown not returning selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been scratching my head for hours trying to solve this problem. I have tried most codes out there regarding this question and have not succeeded in getting a proper guide and answer to working with @html.dropdown. I have a dropdown which gets value from controller ViewBag.

```
  public ActionResult FindBirthStones()
        {
            ViewBag.birthstones = new SelectList(dbcontext.GemStoneByMonths, "GemStoneByMonthId", "EnglishZodiac");
            return View();
        }
```

and in my View I have written.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.EnglishZodiac,(SelectList)ViewBag.birthstones, new { @id = "hello" })
```

I have tried @html.dropdownlist instead of listfor.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("EnglishZodiac", (SelectList)ViewBag.birthstones, new { @id = "hello" })
```

and I want to get the selected value from the dropdownlist or listfor using jquery. I have tried most answers which are

```
 var a=  $("hello").text()
 var a=  $("hello option:selected").text()
var a=  $("hello :selected").text()
```

and none of them work. Can someone please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you do not need to rename `DropDownList`'s id to `hello`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EnglishZodiac, (SelectList)ViewBag.birthstones));
```

Instead, you need to use `#` to get an element by ID inside jQuery. [How do I get the text value of a selected option?](http://How%20do%20I%20get%20the%20text%20value%20of%20a%20selected%20option?)

```
var a = $("#EnglishZodiac option:selected").text();
```

If the script is inside `View.cshtml`, you could even use strongly-typed html helper `Html.IdFor`.

```
$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.EnglishZodiac) option:selected").text();
```

If you want to get the selected value, you could just use `.val()`.

```
var a = $("#EnglishZodiac").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To reference an element by it's id you need to use the hash (#) selector, like this:

```
// To get the text of the selected option
var a = $("#hello option:selected").text();
// To get the value of the selected option
var b = $("#hello").val();
```